# Setup Jinja2 in Django Project

Tags: django, django-templates, jinja2

Newbie question, yet I cannot find a sufficient step-by-step instruction on Jinja2 official website or by googling.

My current Django project is halfway done, and I cannot stand not able to use queryset filter in Django template anymore. So decide to switch to Jinja2.

What I have done: pip install jinja2 to the virtualenv. Then I tried to use Jinja syntax in my template files, which fails.. apparently and sadly

What else do I need to do to make Jinja2 work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to switch to using a rendering method that uses Jinja2 templates instead of Django templates - [coffin](https://github.com/coffin/coffin/) has a helper you can use named [render_to_response](https://github.com/coffin/coffin/#rendering) that should work.

Answer (score 9):

I just want to recommend two alternatives I find very useful.

#### Jinja template tag

One is the jinja template tag which lets you use jinja within django templates as

```
{% jinja %}{{ this_is_jinja(True)}}{% endjinja %}
```

Very useful when you can't / don't want to break the rest of your existing templates.

http://www.mellowmorning.com/2010/08/24/mixing-django-with-jinja2-without-losing-template-debugging/

#### Conditional template engine

The other is conditional loading of template engines based on filename (note I wrote this since I use both template languages):

https://github.com/yuchant/django-jinja2

Comment: Big +1. Both are great suggestions. If you could add a line or two contrasting their pros & cons (security/performance), that'd be very helpful.

Comment: @buffer I don't understand how security plays into this (if your template is compromised.. your server is compromised). As for performance, I don't have any benchmarks for you, but my general conclusion on web development performance is that it should be handled last (never prematurely optimize) since everything must be cached to attain commercial levels of traffic anyways. There is not anything that jumps out at me in these features that would be a red flag of a performance issue vs the default template language.